# imacros, create folder structure as EXTRACT as HREF root

Tags: image, save, structure, directory, imacros

```
TAG POS=4 TYPE=IMG ATTR=STYLE:margin:*15px*&&SCR:*&&ALT:* EXTRACT=HREF
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=D:\\temp\\img\\ FILE=* WAIT=YES
TAG POS=4 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:/upload/images/* CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEPICTUREAS
```

with above code,
the EXTRACT HREF get :

```
"http://ext-domain.com/images/products/78/403/11132/1/279/seagate-ext-drive-(1).jpg"
```

actually there is more than one image on the page, with different names and exts

```
"http://ext-domain.com/images/products/78/403/11132/1/279/seagate-ext-drive-(1).jpg"
".. same as above....................................... /seagate-ext-drive-(2).gif"
".. same as above....................................... /i/seagate-ext-drive-small-(1).gif"
".. same as above....................................... /i/seagate-ext-drive-small-(2).jpg"
```

(sorry `.. same as above.. is ..http.../78/403/11132/1/279/..` ,because still need 10 reputations to post )

and all my images save to :

```
D:\temp\img\
```

How to make imacros save this image to

```
D:\temp\img\78\403\11132\1\279\seagate-ext-drive-(1).jpg
D:\temp\img\78\403\11132\1\279\seagate-ext-drive-(2).gif
D:\temp\img\78\403\11132\1\279\i\seagate-ext-drive-small-(1).gif
D:\temp\img\78\403\11132\1\279\i\seagate-ext-drive-small-(2).jpg
```

I repeat the code from TAG 1 to TAG 4 to get 4 images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
SET myFolder D:\temp\img\
TAG POS=4 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:/upload/images/* EXTRACT=HREF
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/\/upload\/images\/(.*)image\.jpg/)[1];")
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/\\//g, '\\\\');")
ADD myFolder {{!EXTRACT}}
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER={{myFolder}} FILE=image.jpg WAIT=YES
TAG POS=4 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:/upload/images/* CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEPICTUREAS
```

Comment: Hi @Shugar, thanks for your code, It's work with my sample code but when I'm facing with real web with `TypeError: "http://www.ext-domain.com/images/products/78/403/11132/1/279/seagate-ext-drive-(1).jpg".match(...) is null, line 16 (Error code: -1001)` . Actually there is more than one image on the page with different names, I also try to modify your code but not work, sorry I'm not good enough. I edited my question with real html, sorry and hope you can help. thanks

Comment: Hi. Just edit the 3rd line of the code as follows: `SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/.*products\/(.*)seagate.*/)[1];")`

Comment: Really work @Shugar, but I get my filename also converted to path 
`/78/403/11132/1/279/seagate-ext-drive-‌​(1).jpg/seagate-ext-drive-‌​(1).jpg` 
how to make it 
`/78/403/11132/1/279/seagate-ext-drive-‌​(1).jpg`.  
means file name not converted to path
thanks and please help me out for the latest, thank you very much.

Comment: The code works fine with the links provided. I suspect that in fact you have different ones. If you don’t wish to post them here, you may send it to my e-mail ( shugarjs@gmail.com ).